# Jenkins user configure "Extended Email Job Watching", but No configuration available

Tags: jenkins

I want that the signed users can select to receive which jobs' email notification.
I installed the Ext. email notification plug-in, and enabled it in the jobs, and enabled watching for jobs in the overall configuration. but I still can't see anything in the user's property page display.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K058Z.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to activate that feature in the Global Settings:
See: [https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-Globalconfiguration] and look for the checkbox "Enable watching for jobs"; as an administrator, you would want to also enable the triggers that you want users to be able to subscribe to (default is a limited set).

This will still leave the user "Configure" screen with no possible action. Users have to subscribe to specific triggers from the job page itself, using a link (not in the left margin menu, but on the main page) named "Watch Job" whihc takes you to a separate page to choose the triggers. Then this will show in the User's Configure page.

Comment: I believe this too.  But in Jenkins v2.46.3 / Email extension 2.52 there is no "Watch Job" link.  I know, my Jenkins installation is as old as this question, if I ever get to upgrade it I'll update this comment ;)

Comment: I do not see the "Watch Job" link either and I've selected "Enable watching for jobs". Any ideas?